# maven list active profiles in filtering

Tags: spring, maven

I am trying to get a list of all of the active profiles in maven and use them as a variable in resource filtering.

In particular, when I run something like

```
mvn package -Pprofile1,profile2
```

I want to expose the string "profile1,profile2" as a variable in resource filtering.

For example, in my pom.xml file I have the maven war plugin configured as follows to allow resource filtering on everything in the src/main/resources/META-INF directory, and I have a few profiles defined:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <webResources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <!-- Only include the META-INF directory -->
                <includes>
                    <include>META-INF/*</include>
                </includes>
                <!-- replace placeholder values -->
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
...
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>profile1</id>
        <properties>
            <environment>profile1</environment>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>profile2</id>
        <properties>
            <environment>profile2</environment>
        </properties>
    </profile>
```

Under the META-INF directory, I have a context.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/platform">
    <Environment name="spring.profiles.active" value="${environment}" type="java.lang.String" />
</Context>
```

I tried setting the property "environment" under each profile but the resulting context.xml file only uses the last "environment" variable (e.g. value=profile2).

I also tried using this: `value=${project.activeProfiles}` but that returns some sort of list of objects.  It would be great if I could iterate over this list and extract the ids from the profiles to build the string, but I couldn't find any documentation in the maven resources plugin on doing this.

What I'm ultimately trying to do is set the `spring.profiles.active` variable as an environment variable via the context.xml file, and that variable is the same as the maven build profiles.

Comment: One thought about your pom file. Why are defining the `src/main/resources` as webResources cause `src/main/resources` is a usual resource which is copied during resource phase and if you like to filter it define it like this...

Comment: I did that to place the context.xml file into the META-INF folder, I'm not sure if that's the proper way to do it, but it does work for me.

Comment: Hey, any luck with this? I am also looking for a way to "I could iterate over this list and extract the ids from the profiles to build the string".

Answer (score 0):

You can list the active profiles via:

```
mvn help:active-profiles
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not looking to list the active profiles (I already know what those are as they are explicity set), but to have maven use resource filtering to replace a placeholder variable with all active profiles.  Sorry if my question isn't clear.